# Using https with grafana/caddy on docker compose

Tags: docker-compose, caddy

I'm trying to understand how to implement https with grafana/caddy in docker compose without a domain name.

Currently, I access grafana via http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:3000/

I would like this to be https, but am struggling to understand how to generate the cert and have it work as expected. I think `letsencrypt` requires a domain which I don't have.

```yaml
version: "3"
networks:
    monitor-net:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    grafana_data: {}
services:
    grafana:
        image: grafana/grafana:8.4.4
        container_name: grafana
        volumes:
            - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
            - ./grafana/provisioning/dashboards:/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards
            - ./grafana/provisioning/datasources:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources
        environment:
            - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=${GF_ADMIN_USER}
            - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${GF_ADMIN_PASS}
            - GF_USERS_ALLOW_SIGN_UP=false
        restart: unless-stopped
        expose:
            - 3000
        networks:
            - monitor-net
        labels:
            org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

    caddy:
        image: caddy:2.3.0
        container_name: caddy
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
            - "9090:9090"
            - "9093:9093"
            - "9091:9091"
        volumes:
            - ./caddy:/etc/caddy
        environment:
            - ADMIN_USER=${GF_ADMIN_USER}
            - ADMIN_PASSWORD=${GF_ADMIN_PASS}
            - ADMIN_PASSWORD_HASH=${ADMIN_PASS_HASH}
        restart: unless-stopped
        networks:
            - monitor-net
        labels:
            org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"
```

I'm assuming I would create a volume on `/etc/caddy/certs` where I'd store the certificates, but don't know how to generate it for IP only or how it gets recognized by caddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Caddy for IP with SSL

> By default, Caddy serves all sites over HTTPS.
> Caddy serves IP addresses and local/internal hostnames over HTTPS using self-signed certificates that are automatically trusted locally (if permitted).
> Examples: localhost, 127.0.0.1

[Offical Docs Here](https://caddyserver.com/docs/automatic-https)

in your `Caddyfile` you have to add something like this

```
http://192.168.1.25:3000 {
   reverse_proxy grafana_ip:3000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Caddy [does not support generating HTTPS certificates for IP addresses](https://caddyserver.com/docs/automatic-https#hostname-requirements). Additionally, Let's Encrypt [does not currently support issuing certificates for bare IP addresses](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/planned-rfc-8738-support-pulled/152057/3).

However, it does appear that [ZeroSSL supports generating certificates for IPs](https://help.zerossl.com/hc/en-us/articles/360060119973-Is-It-Possible-To-Generate-a-SSL-Certificate-for-an-IP-Address-). You could try using [these instructions](https://caddy.community/t/using-zerossls-acme-endpoint/9406) to change one or all of your sites to use ZeroSSL, but I wasn't able to get this to work on my test server.

The best option is probably to get a domain that you can point at your server, and then serve it from there.